# Python multiprocessing 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-itertools

I am trying to speed up my python script using multiprocessing.  This script is supposed to process one word at a time from a file, where each word is on its own line in the file. Most of the time it works, but sometimes a 'NoneType' object is passed to process_chunk, and this error is thrown:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I based my code off of [this template][1].

This is the code that creates the Pool:

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
with open(filename, 'r') as swaps_file:
    for chunk in grouper(2000, swaps_file):
        p.map(process_chunk, chunk)
```

This is the grouper which should be breaking the file into chunks:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, padvalue=None):
    """grouper(3, 'abcdefg', 'x') -->
    ('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g','x','x')"""
    return itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=padvalue)
```

And this is the processing of each chunk. I only want to process one word at a time:

```
def process_chunk(d):
    word = d.strip()
    do_stuff(word)
```

d.strip() should be removing the newline from the end of the line so I only process the word. The problem is, sometimes process_chunk gets called on a 'NoneType' object, and I'm not sure why. On the github template, a user said

> I did a few test runs with this code and observed something like this: If (number of rows in the test_data % number of multiprocessing.pools == 0) then code finishes okay else code throw error. Can you please confirm this is expected? If yes, how should I work around this ?

This does seem to be the problem, as the number of times process_chunk gets called on a NoneType object is equal to the leftover number of pools (the 2000 value passed to grouper minus number of rows in file % 2000). If this is indeed the problem, is the only way around it to change the number of pools or catch the exception? Is there another issue?
[1]: https://gist.github.com/ngcrawford/2237170

Comment: Note the example in the docstring (specifically the `x`s): `grouper(3, 'abcdefg', 'x') -->
    ('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g','x','x')`. You don't specify a `padvalue`, so it defaults to `None`. That means that unless your file has an exact multiple of 2000 lines, the last chunk will be padded with `None`s at the end. Just specify a different pad value, or check for `None`s in the function.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that makes sense, thanks! What exactly does the 2000 mean, as I'm assuming it doesn't mean 2000 threads are running at once.

Comment: Note the docstring example. With a `3` passed, it groups the input into groups of 3. It looks off here though. They're having it grouped into chunks of 2000 lines, but then each chunk is passed to `map`. I would think you'd want to do simply `p.map(process_chunk, grouper(2000, swaps_file))` instead, then have `process_chunk` actually handle chunks. With how it is now, `process_chunk` is processing parts of chunks, not whole chunks, which seems less efficient. Doing tiny jobs over multiprocessing isn't a great idea.

Comment: And it terms of how many processes are running at once, since you haven't passed anything to `Pool`, I believe it defaults to the number of logical cores in your system.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think it is actually processing whole chunks, as the value returned by grouper returns a list of lists, and I believe each of these lists is mapped to a process.

Comment: Each chunk returned by `grouper` is being passed to `map`, and `map` will run `process_chunk` on *each element of the chunk*, over multiple processes.